# Check specific ‘claim’ is still valid for logged in user using ADFS + Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, adfs3.0

I am using ADFS for Claim based-authorization, I need to check specific ‘claim’ is still valid 
(implements a validate claim method) by key in a Claim Name in text box and Click Validate button.

I am not sure how I can validate specific claim again for logged in user. I tried doing lots of research but could not found any useful resource.

Thx in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't you send it to ADFS for validation?

Comment: yes , I did validation using AD FS. once done with validation I need to check again from list of claim is still valid or not.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to get claims from ADFS is to authenticate and look through the list of claims in the token.

It sounds like what you need is to go to AD directly as per [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/90142/Everything-in-Active-Directory-via-C-NET-Using) and get e.g. the user groups

i.e. "IsUserGroupMember" – This method will validate whether the User is a Member of a Group